# Qt Quick Creator (QML) for pyside2/pyqt5 python users

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm exploring the possibility to use Qt Quick Creator to generate .qml files and load them afterwards in a python project (PyQt5 or PySide2).
But when I create a new Qt Quick Application, Qt Creator asks me to select a valid kit, which I dont have because I won't use C++. I dont won't to set up a C++ compiler that I will never use.

What I basically need is an explanaion to start using Qt Quick Creator for pyside2/pyqt5 users.

My understanding of the work flow is to generate .qml files. Once, I have generated files, I guess I will be able to load them in python using these imports:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl
```

Comment: How have you installed Qt Creator?

Comment: I have Creator 4.6.1 (Community) from https://www.qt.io/download with default options. But I when I do, New File->QtQuick Application ... I am blocked at the "Kits" step because I dont have and dont want any Kits.

Comment: What I do in the first case is to create a project using the following form: `File-> New File or Project ...-> Other Project-> Qt Quick Ui prototype`, 
Check if you can create a project in that way

Comment: This method works. Thanks a million. Btw, do you prefer using  Qt Quick Creator or Qt Designer in your UI python application ?

Comment: Although I do not use much Qt Designer since I design it manually, the structure is simple, but QML is handled in a different way so I use Qt Quick Creator to make my life easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a QML project without using C ++ what you should do is follow the following steps

```
└── File New File or Project ...
    └── Other Project
        └── Qt Quick Ui prototype
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I can go on now.